# sql IN clause only returning the current row, instead of selected ones

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm developing a site which is supposed to return similar movies by comparing the metadata from the movie that is selected, with the metadata from the ones in the database.

At the moment, I'm just comparing the *classification rating*. For example, if you've selected a movie that has a rating of ***R*** or ***MA***, then the results returned should be something with a similar classification (ie: ***M***, ***MA*** or ***R***).

So far, this is what my **SQL** and **PHP** look like.

```
$rating = $data->rating;
if($rating === "MA" || $rating === "R"){
    $rating = "M, MA, R";
}

$rating = "rating IN (" . $rating . ")";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE unique_id <> ? AND " . $rating . " LIMIT 10";
```

If the **SQL** is output to the page, it should look like `SELECT * ... AND rating IN (M, MA, R) ...`, which it does. However, instead of the returned results being of all those movies that have a rating of ***M***, ***MA*** or ***R*** (not including the selected movie), it will return only the selected movie.

Here's an **example** of my current database table:

```
+----+--------+--------+-----------+
| id | title  | rating | unique_id |
+----+--------+--------+-----------+
|  1 | movieA | R      | idA       |
|  2 | movieB | MA     | idB       |
|  3 | movieC | M      | idC       |
|  4 | movieD | MA     | idD       |
|  5 | movieE | PG     | idE       |
+----+--------+--------+-----------+
```

For `movieA`, it should be returning all movies apart from `movieE`. If it was `movieC`, it should be returning `2, 4 and 5`.

I feel like I have used the `IN` clause correctly, so I'm confused as to why this is not working.

All help is appreciated, Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the ratings are strings, they need to be quoted.

```
if($rating === "MA" || $rating === "R"){
    $rating = "'M', 'MA', 'R'";
} else {
    $rating = "'$rating'";
}
```

See [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: I'll test now! Thanks :)

Comment: Will accept answer in 3 minutes :) thanks for the reference btw

Answer (score 1):

If the `rating` column is of type `varchar`, then you have to surround single quotes on each of the search strings.

**Change**:

```
$rating = "M, MA, R";
```

**To**:

```
$rating = "'M', 'MA', 'R'";
```

And the resulting query would look like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM movies 
 WHERE unique_id <> ? 
   AND rating IN ('M', 'MA', 'R')
 LIMIT 10
```

And applying it, you should be getting the expected result.

Comment: He also needs to add the quotes when he's not assigning a list of ratings.

Comment: That is the basic. So long as the column being searched is string, using single quotes is mandatory for correct results.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **strings** instead of **integers**, add quotes (`'`) in between each element. For example:

```
IN(M, MA, R)
```

Would then become, instead:

```
IN('M','MA','R')
```